# How to activate OSGI bundle?

Tags: osgi, bundle, apache-felix, sling, osgi-bundle

I am working in Adobe CQ5. I made my project that contains only implementation, and the project title is Web Crawler.

And that project is started by one class that simply adds initial seeds.

I made OSGI bundle of my project and I deploy that also.

Now my question is how can I start my bundle, i.e, how can I add seeds ?

For that I read [this link](http://blog.knowhowlab.org/2010/10/osgi-tutorial-4-ways-to-activate-code.html) that tells me to make **Activator class** and put your function in the **start method**. I done the same. But that does not helps me to run the bundle.

Please help me how can I run the given bundle.

**Edit No. 1**

Can you tell me how can I make **MANIFEST.MF** file given in given tutorial ?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [bndtools tutorial](http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html) which is the easiest way to get you started with OSGi

bndtools is a user friendly tool based on Eclipse. With bndtools, you won't get lost in plugin hell. bndtools will also help you avoid BundleActivators since they were not such a good idea, Declarative Services is what OSGi should have been from day one. It also allows you to test the bundles without having to restart.

Comment: I made the bundle and it activates also. Now I found one more problem. Can we do a small chat please ?

Comment: I think that forfeits the model of Stackoverflow? I help for the general public, if you want to hire me for consulting you can find my details on my website ...

Comment: Ohk. I will post another question for that.

Answer (score 2):

to create the manifest, if you are using maven (you should) you can use the maven bundle plugin. It will automatically generate a manifest file for you.

Then, to deploy and start your bundle you can use the maven-sling-plugin, which can deploy your bundles into sling.

If you want to manually activate your bundle, CQ5 provides a web based osgi console. you can activate it there. If it fails, there is probably an error in the start method of the activator class.